# How to use GMock check base class function is called

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, googletest, googlemock

This is very closely related to [How to use gmock to test that a class calls it's base class' methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487301/how-to-use-gmock-to-test-that-a-class-calls-its-base-class-methods) but I'm struggling to get this working with my example.

I'm using GTest and GMock to test drive a new feature so I have a base class...

```
class SimpleObject
{
public:
    explicit SimpleObject() {}

    virtual void moveX(int dX)
    {
        // Do important stuff like updating position, bounding box etc.
    }

    // ...
};
```

Based on other TDD I have a derived class and the new feature is such that when I call moveX on the derived object it will do something specific, however it also needs to do the important stuff in SimpleObject::moveX.

I already have test driven unit tests related to the SimpleObject::moveX function so I don't want to repeat them for the derived class. As long as I know SimpleObject::moveX is called then everything's hunky dory.

Anyway, based on the above link and following TDD I've ended up with the following.

The derived class:

```
    class ComplexObject : public SimpleObject
    {
    public:
        virtual void moveX(int dX)
        {
            // Do something specific
        }
    };
```

The 'testable' class:

```
class TestableComplexObject : public ComplexObject
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(moveX, void(int dX));

    void doMoveX(int dX)
    {
        SimpleObject::moveX(dX);
    }
};
```

The test:

```
TEST_F(ATestableComplexObject, CallsBaseClassMoveXWhenMoveXIsCalled)
{
    int dX(8);
    TestableComplexObject obj;

    EXPECT_CALL(obj, moveX(dX))
                .Times(1)
                .WillRepeatedly(testing::Invoke(&obj, &TestableComplexObject::doMoveX));

    obj.moveX(dX);
}
```

If I run my tests then everything passes. This isn't correct because as you can see ComplexObject::moveX doesn't do anything.

Also, regardless of what I put in doMoveX (which I thought was meant to set up my expectations) the tests will still pass.

I'm obviously missing something simple here, so any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to design your `ComplexObject` in a way that checking if `SimpleObject::moveX` was called is possible. One way to do it: encapsulate this base call with some other function that can be mocked:

```
class ComplexObject : public SimpleObject
{
public:
    virtual void moveX(int dX)
    {
        // Call base function
        baseMoveX(dx);
        // Do something specific
    }
protected: 
    virtual void baseMoveX(int dX)
    {
        SimpleObject::moveX(dx);
    }
};
```

Then in your `Testable` class just mock this base function:

```
class TestableComplexObject : public ComplexObject
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(baseMoveX, void(int dX));
};
```

You cannot mock just `moveX` because - there is no way to distinguish between base and derived in such context.

So - your test can look like this:

```
TEST_F(ATestableComplexObject, CallsBaseClassMoveXWhenMoveXIsCalled)
{
    int dX(8);
    TestableComplexObject obj;

    EXPECT_CALL(obj, baseMoveX(dX))
                .WillOnce(testing::Invoke([&obj] (auto dx) {obj.SimpleObject::moveX(dx); }));

    obj.moveX();
}
```

---

**[UPDATE]**

As it is discovered in comments - there is still a problem how to ensure ComplexObject::baseMoveX() calls SimpleObject::moveX.

The possible solution is to put one more class in between ComplexObject and SimpleObject.

```
template <typename BaseObject>
class IntermediateObject : public BaseObject
{
public:
    virtual void baseMoveX(int dX)
    {
        BaseObject::moveX(dx);
    }
};
```

With test ensuring this really happens:

```
class TestableBaseMock
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(moveX, void(int dX));
};

TEST(IntermediateObject Test, shallCallBaseMoveX)
{
    const int dX = 8;
    IntermediateObject<TestableBaseMock> objectUnderTest;
    TestableBaseMock& baseMock = objectUnderTest;

    EXPECT_CALL(baseMock, moveX(dX));

    objectUnderTest.baseMoveX(dx);
}
```

Then - put it between Simple and Complex classes:

```
class ComplexObject : public IntermediateObject<SimpleObject>
{
public:
    virtual void moveX(int dX)
    {
        // Call base function
        baseMoveX(dx);
        // Do something specific
    }
};
```

---

At the end - I just want to emphasize that changing your original design - to use aggregation instead of inheritance (aka decorator design pattern) is the best way. First - as you can see in my answer - trying to stay with inheritance make the design worse if we want to test it. Second - tests for decorator kind of design are much simpler as it showed in one of the answers...

Comment: Ok that makes sense and I can see how that would work. However, what if I had a lot more derived base class functions. Is it still an acceptable good design to have all those functions effectively duplicated?

Comment: Implementing your changes causes it to seg fault at the obj.moveX(dX) line, presumably because it's a mock?

Comment: I've tried this example and had ComplexObject::baseMoveX and ComplexObject::moveX empty. The first run the tests failed so I put the baseMoveX call in ComplexObject::moveX which passed. It shouldn't pass because my ComplexObject::baseMoveX does nothing. So this is the same situation I was in before

Comment: So probably I did not get what you asked exactly... From TC you presented in question it was clear to me that you expect `SimpleObject::moveX(dx)` to be called from `ComplexObject::moveX`. IF this is not a case - then please clarify your question  - e.g. show the code you have in `ComplexObject::moveX` and what you wanted to check in TC...

Comment: That's correct, I expect SimpleObject::moveX(dX) to be called when ComplexObject::moveX is called. As I'm test driving this ComplexObject::moveX is empty

Comment: If the test passes with baseMoveX empty then it is redundant as it doesn't test what I need

Comment: TDD shall proceed like this: You don't have baseMove in your complex move. So the test fails. You added it, so the test succeeded. The how to be sure baseMoveX calls simple moveX? You are at this point.

Comment: I'd use some class template between simple and complex classes. That class between just add baseMoveX. Then, for this class template test base moveX is called... Icannot update my answer since i write from phone...

Comment: Ok. I just saw you put answer with decarator pattern. That's fine answer. Just your question tend me to think you want to trst current design...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, with a tweak to the design I am able to test what I want.

Firstly, create an interface for SimpleObject:

```
class ISimpleObject
{
public:
    virtual void moveX(int dX) = 0;
};
```

My SimpleObject class then implements this:

```
class SimpleObject : public ISimpleObject
{
public:
    explicit SimpleObject() {}

    virtual void moveX(int dX)
    {
        (void) dX;
        // Do important stuff like updating position, bounding box etc.
    }
};
```

Instead of ComplexObject inheriting from SimpleObject, it inherits from the interface and owns a SimpleObject (i.e. it 'has a' rather than 'is a'). The constructor ensures we pass in a SimpleObject and it's this injection that makes mocking easier.

```
class ComplexObject : public ISimpleObject
{
public:
    ComplexObject(SimpleObject *obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    virtual void moveX(int dX)
    {
        _obj->moveX(dX);
    }

private:
    SimpleObject *_obj;
};
```

Now I simply mock the calls I'm interested in from SimpleObject

```
class SimpleObjectMock : public SimpleObject
{
public:
        MOCK_METHOD1(moveX, void(int dX));
        // Do important stuff like updating position, bounding box etc.
};
```

The test is simplified too

```
TEST_F(AComplexObject, CallsBaseClassMoveXWhenMoveX)
{
    int dX(8);

    SimpleObjectMock mock;
    ComplexObject obj(&mock);

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, moveX(dX)).Times(1);

    obj.moveX(dX);
}
```

The behaviour is as expected. If the ComplexObject::moveX function is empty (as it will be at the start) then the test fails. It will only pass when you call SimpleObject::moveX.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that, in method `TestableComplexObject::doMoveX`, you are calling method `SimpleObject::moveX`. This is why everything passes. You are supposed to call the method `moveX` that belongs to class `ComplexObject`. Therefore, changing method `doMoveX` to:

```
void doMoveX(int dX)
{
    ComplexObject::moveX(dX);
}
```

will solve your problem.

There is one more issue with the code you've posted. The last statement in the test body should be:

```
obj.moveX(dX);
```

but I guess this is just an error made while writing the question?

Hope this helps!

Comment: The tests pass regardless of what I put in doMoveX which is where the confusion came from. Plus, if I call ComplexObject::doMoveX then surely this will call the derived function and not the base function I need to ensure is called?

Comment: Yes, the last statement was a typo. I'll edit the original post